Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Class cannot be invoked without 'new' in the file shape-builder.js package file
I have upgraded the angular from the version 5.2 to 17 and kendo to the version 17.
After the upgradate I am facing the runtime issue

Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Class cannot be invoked without 'new'

The detailed error is as below:

shape-builder.js:8
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Class cannot be invoked without 'new'
at new ShapeBuilder (shape-builder.js:8:15)
at 24009 (shape-builder.js:50:24)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 86125 (core-export.js:5:40)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 57344 (user-events.js:621:26)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 94860 (kendo.dataviz.chart.js:1669:24)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at 39749 (kendo.dataviz.stock.js:288:20)

as shape-builder.js is a package file, I am not sure whether modifying this file is a right approach or not.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue please?
I have tried installing shape-builder package inside node modules which didn't work
